# Why does the primeng p-table element throw an error but still update the record when editing a row?

Tags: angular, primeng, p-table

I'm referring to the following primeng p-table example:

url: https://primeng.org/table#Edit (Click on the stackblitz icon in the top right corner as highlighted in blue below)

[image]

As you can see if I update the price to an invalid value & then click the check mark,

the toast error message displays, but it still updates the record!

[image]

How can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of typescript not doing runtime type checking. The ngModel for price is binded to product.price. As the user inputs, for example, a string into the *price* field, the ngModel updates, even though the *string* type is not compatible with the *number* type. Typescript does not care, as it does not check types at runtime. In the method onRowEditSave(), the program checks that product.price is greater than zero. This is not true when product.price is a string. Therefore, the statement evaluates to false, and the program throws the error 'Invalid Price.'

To fix this, you could use a [p-inputNumber](https://primeng.org/inputnumber) instead of using a regular input with the pInputText directive. The inputNumber component does not allow the user to input normal text, just numbers.

Comment: thanks I'll have a look at rather using p-inputNumber instead.

Comment: changing the component to p-inputNumber has the same effect, displays the Invalid price message but still saves the record.